# is it good to use "enum" for same value in database as well as in program(JAVA)?

Tags: java, mysql, enums

This is my employee_detail:

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE_DETAIL(
    EMP_ID INT(10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    FIRST_NAME  VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    LAST_NAME   VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    EMAIL_ID    VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    EMP_DOB     DATE NOT NULL,
    GENDER ENUM('MALE','FEMALE','TRANSGENDER'),
    EMP_SALARY  DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL,
    CONTACT_NO  BIGINT (10)  NOT NULL,
    OCCUPATION  VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    DESIGNATION VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    DATE_OF_JOINING DATE NOT NULL
);
```

AND 
This is java enum file :

```
import java.util.Enumeration;

public enum Gender{
        Male, Female, Transgender;
    }
```

Please correct me in 'dbtable' as well as how to avoid use of "enum" in both places. I want to use "enum" only in one place so where should i use it(best suitable).
Please provide some good references.

Comment: Please google for 'ENUM is evil'